# How to generate viewable s3 url nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I use the below code to get the signed url. I am getting a signed url and once i open the url its downloading the file. But i want a url where i can show the file. Like opening file in a new tab.

I am using aws-sdk package and generate s3 as below

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
            Expires: options.expires || 300,
            Bucket: config.awsBucket,
            Key: key,
            // ACL: 'public-read',
            ResponseContentDisposition :'inline;filename=report.pdf'}, 
          function(err, url) {
            if (err) {
                return deferred.reject(err);
            }
            return deferred.resolve(url);
        });
```

Does anyone know how to generate a url where i can show the file.

Comment: What is not working, can you try to print the url before resolve and see the signed url?

Comment: I get a good aws url but, on openning the url the file is getting downloaded rather than showing the file in browser

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set Content-Type when uploading to S3 with AWS CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643455/how-do-i-set-content-type-when-uploading-to-s3-with-aws-cli)

Comment: Another example of how you can do it with code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979558/saving-an-image-stored-on-s3-using-node-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you didn't set the `Content-Type` correctly when you uploaded the file, this behavior is to be expected, because the [default type is `binary/octet-stream`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html), which the browser correctly determines cannot be displayed inline.

You can work around it by setting `ResponseContentType` in your `getSignedUrl()` request to the correct value.

The correct type for a PDF file is [`application/pdf`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/312258/1695906).