# download image on aws lambda nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda

I need to download an image to my aws lambda function and use it for later use.
I have tried to use `http.get()` method but it requires local file system to place the image, which i guess is not available in case of lambda function.

I have also tried to use `request.get` method which is also not returning correct response to me.

Currently my function looks like:

```
function download_image(image_url){
    return new Promise(resolve =>{
        request.get(image_url, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                // let data = "data:" + response.headers["content-type"] + ";base64," + new Buffer(body).toString('base64');
                resolve("Downloaded")
            }
            else{
                resolve("Failed Downloaded")
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I am openly looking for a way to store image on s3 or if I can store it in dynamo db using any format.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is that your handler function? Or, is that a utility function that your handler function uses?

Comment: @dashmug it is a utility function i have writen

Answer (score 0):

im fairly sure you can use http.get in a lambda. 
in concept you'd be doing the request, saving it to a byte array or buffer then writing that to s3. s3 makes sense for files and the retrieving is way easier than dynamodb, and also dynamodb you pay for writes and reads.

[Saving an image stored on s3 using node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979558/saving-an-image-stored-on-s3-using-node-js)